# Sub activity disables Bluetooth Adapter

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have added an `onDestroy` in my **Main activity**

```
@Override

protected void onDestroy() {

        if (BTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            BTAdapter.disable();
        }

        this.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

In my Main Activity I start another activity through Navigation Drawer

```
if (id == R.id.nav_devices) {

            intent = new Intent("com.navigationwithrssi.RSSIActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

But when I come back to my **Main Activity** (using the default back button in Toolbar), the RSSIActivity automatically disables Bluetooth Adapter.

I just want my Main Activity to be able to do that, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem fixed. It was actually pretty easy, on the tutorial about Providing Up Navigation on developer.android.com

I just put this code in my `onOptionsItemSelected` method

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Also I made the launch mode of my Parent Activity as `<singleTop>`

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

What it does is rather than creating a new instance of your parent activity, it just brings it to the top of the stack.